# application of d3.js example function to crossfilter geoChoroplethChart

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to understand how I can apply functions from the d3.js examples to a map, specifically a geoChoroplethChart that *importantly* relies on functionality from the [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) library.

In the Mike Bostock examples there is one called [*Zoom to Bounding Box II*](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675), which will zoom to focus in on the selected entity and center it in the viewing area.

The code for the geoChoroplethChart seems to take functions as addendums, i.e. they're affixed to the map function with a `.`as shown in the following code snippet.

I'm perplexed as to how I can incorporate the zoom methods from the [*Zoom to Bounding Box II*](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675) example.

Should I try to modify them such that I can added them as arguments, affixed with a `.`?

Should I re-implement all the functions applied to my geoChoroplethChart as independent?

I've been searching the web for answers on the correct way to approach this problem but as of yet I've not found any clear guidance.

```
        //This is the data for the Map
    d3.json("data/europe.json", function (error, eu) { 

        console.log('map', eu)
        usChart
        .width(590)
        .height(500)
        .projection(projection
                    .scale((1200 + 1) / 2 )
                    .translate([660 / 4, 3360 / 4])
                    .precision(.1)
                    )
                .dimension(countries)
                .group(countriesJobsdSum)

                    .filterHandler(function(dimension, filter){     
    dimension.filter(function(d) {return usChart.filter() != null ? d.indexOf
    (usChart.filter()) >= 0 : true;}); // perform filtering
    return filter; // return the actual filter value
 })

                .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(
                    ["#8c857d", "#d982ab", "#d9525e", "#a63f52", "#8c6976", "#55b1b1", "#637e9e"])
                )
                .colorDomain([0, 200])
                .colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? usChart.colors()(d) : '#ccc'; })
                .overlayGeoJson(eu.features, "countries", function (d) {
                    return d.properties.name;
                    //return d.properties.Country;
                })
                .transitionDuration(0)
                .title(function (d) {
                    return "Country: " + d.key + "\nNumber of Jobs: " + numberFormat(d.value ? d.value : 0) ;
                });
```

All of my code can be found [here](https://github.com/smenglish/dash_snow).